# Tailwindcss does not get loaded in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using the following packages and have installed tailwindcss in the following project folder `/home/admin/Desktop/Code/main_project/client/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "web3": "^1.6.1",
    "web3-eth-contract": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}
```

My `tailwind.config.js` looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

As you can see my react-project lies in a subfolder.

My `postcss.config.js` looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

This is my `index.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

In my `index.js` I am loading my `index.css`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from "./redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

My `App.js` looks like the following:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "./redux/blockchain/blockchainActions";
import { fetchData } from "./redux/data/dataActions";


import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const blockchain = useSelector((state) => state.blockchain);
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  const [CONFIG, SET_CONFIG] = useState({
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS: "",
    SCAN_LINK: "",
    NETWORK: {
      NAME: "",
      SYMBOL: "",
      ID: 0,
    },
    NFT_NAME: "",
    SYMBOL: "",
    MAX_SUPPLY: 1,
    WEI_COST: 0,
    DISPLAY_COST: 0,
    GAS_LIMIT: 0,
    MARKETPLACE: "",
    MARKETPLACE_LINK: "",
    SHOW_BACKGROUND: false,
  });

  const getData = () => {
    if (blockchain.account !== "" && blockchain.smartContract !== null) {
      dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
    }
  };

  const getConfig = async () => {
    const configResponse = await fetch("/config/config.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    const config = await configResponse.json();
    SET_CONFIG(config);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getConfig();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [blockchain.account]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Welcome</h1>
    <>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, the components in my `App.js` do not get rendered with tailwindcss.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Could you show your App.js?

Comment: @IgorLoskutov Thx for your reply. Please find above my updated question. Furthermore, my full react-projects lies in a client subfolder. However, as I use relative paths I do not think this might be an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind css 3.0.5 classes is not working with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70403408/tailwind-css-3-0-5-classes-is-not-working-with-react)

Comment: Update to react-scripts v5, [tailwind requires it](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) when integrating with CRA.